# how to maintain the same angular template URL before and after minification | Grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I am facing an issue with the base URL for my directive templates.

1. I have a custom directives defined with in template URL path.
2. I have a grunt html 2 js task, where I need to pass the base path, so that it can match with the actual un-minified directive base path.

How do I pass the normal javascript base URL to grunt task?

This is what I tried:

index.html:

```
<html>
 ......
<script> var basePath = 'basePath'></script>
</html>
```

directive.js:

```
angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', myDirective)
function myDirective(basePath){
 return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: basePath+'/myDir.html'
        }
}
myDirective.$inject = ['basePath'];
```

Since my actual js template URL is not matching with the html2 js created js file path. It is not loading the templates from the html2js file, but it is loading templates from the actual folder which should not happen.

Grunt task:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
  grunt.config('html2js',{
    html2js: {
    options:{
      base:'basePath',
      module: 'templates',
      singleModule:  true,
      useStrict: true
    },
    files: {
      '../my/my.tpl.js':
        ['my/**/*.html'],

    }
  }
  });
};
```

Comment: I would suggest to use dedicated task for this, something like `grunt-angular-templates`.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Angular constant:

```
angular.module('myModule').constant("basePath", "http://example.com");

angular.module('myModule').directive('myDirective', myDirective)
function myDirective(basePath){
 return {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: basePath+'/myDir.html'
        }
}
myDirective.$inject = ['basePath'];
```

For more information, see [AngularJS angular.Module API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module)